# Connecting to confluent kafka cloud from flink sql

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, confluent-cloud

I get the below error when I try to connect to [Confluent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent,_Inc.) cloud.

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLSv1.3 SSLContext not available
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory.createSSLContext(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:268)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory.configure(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:173)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.instantiateSslEngineFactory(SslFactory.java:140)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:180)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLSv1.3 SSLContext not available
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory.createSSLContext(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:243)
```

The flink SQL I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_source_table
(
    headers     VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    id          VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3) NULL,
    type        VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    contentJson VARCHAR NOT NULL
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'kafka',
    'topic-pattern' = 'kafka_topic__.+?',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'some.aws.confluent.cloud:9092',
    'properties.group.id' = 'some-id-1',
    'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
    'format' = 'json',
    'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601',
    'scan.topic-partition-discovery.interval'= '60000',
    'json.fail-on-missing-field' = 'false',
    'json.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true',
    'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_SSL',
    'properties.sasl.mechanism' = 'PLAIN',
    'properties.sasl.jaas.config' = 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=*** password=***;',
    'properties.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm' = 'https'
);
```

When I check the Java version in the [Kubernetes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubernetes) pod that run the task manager I see `11.0.18`. I get this by running `System.getProperty("java.version")`.

UPDATE
my gradle file looks like this:
implementation "org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java:${flinkVersion}"
implementation "org.apache.flink:flink-table-api-java-bridge:${flinkVersion}"
implementation "org.apache.flink:flink-table-planner_${scalaVersion}:${flinkVersion}"
implementation "org.apache.flink:flink-json:${flinkVersion}"
implementation "org.apache.flink:flink-clients:${flinkVersion}"

```
//this seems to be needed : removing this is causing error in guice JsonProperty.Naming
implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${jacksonVersion}"
implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:${jacksonVersion}"

implementation "org.apache.flink:flink-statebackend-rocksdb:${flinkVersion}"

//needed for a local flink ui to show when running environment = local
implementation "org.apache.flink:flink-runtime-web:${flinkVersion}"

implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:${log4jVersion}"
implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:${log4jVersion}"
implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:${log4jVersion}"

implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.2'
implementation 'com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:1.4.9'
implementation 'org.rocksdb:rocksdbjni:7.9.2'

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Dependencies that should be part of the shadow jar, e.g.
// connectors. These must be in the flinkShadowJar configuration!
// --------------------------------------------------------------
flinkShadowJar files('libs/flink-connector-kafka-1.16.0.jar')
flinkShadowJar "org.apache.flink:flink-connector-base:${flinkVersion}"

flinkShadowJar "org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.10.0"
flinkShadowJar "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26"
flinkShadowJar "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${jacksonVersion}"
flinkShadowJar "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:${jacksonVersion}"
flinkShadowJar "com.sailpoint:atlas:${ATLAS_VERSION}"
flinkShadowJar "com.sailpoint:atlas-event:${ATLAS_VERSION}"
flinkShadowJar "com.google.inject:guice:5.1.0"
flinkShadowJar "org.apache.flink:flink-s3-fs-hadoop:${flinkVersion}"
flinkShadowJar 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.2'
flinkShadowJar 'com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:1.4.9'
```

What could I be missing here?

Comment: I guess you have to connect to 9093 port.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using [Flink's SQL connector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/kafka/), which has shaded the Kafka Clients JAR in there. Because of the shading, that means that the JAAS Config needs to be pointed to the shaded PlainLoginModule, e.g.

```
'properties.sasl.jaas.config' = 'org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="key" password="value";'
```

Comment: I have update the include my gradle file. Adding the above suggestion i get `No LoginModule found for org.apache.flink.kafka.shaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule` error. `PlainLoginModule` class seems to coming from kafka-clients-3.0.2.jar.
Also i use `FROM fedora:37` image to build task manager add use this to installjava

```RUN dnf -y update \
    && dnf -y install java-11-openjdk  gettext jemalloc-devel snappy wget glibc-langpack-en \
    && dnf -y clean all```

Comment: Your Gradle file doesn't contain any Flink Kafka connector. It's not bundled with Flink, so you'll need to add that as a dependency